# Data in ckeditor doesn't insert to db when i apply sneek/laravel-xss-middleware

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, xss

When i update data from ckeditor and it didn't save to database properly it saves only text but table div and inline style didn't save after I apply sneek/laravel-xss-middleware. 
What xss middleware that not affect to text editor? 
I tried others but it can't prevent xss. 
Can anyone recommend ?

I use nessus to scan web for security after i use htmlpurifier it still show:

**CGI Generic HTML Injections (quick test)**

**Synopsis**
The remote web server may be prone to HTML injections.

**Description**
The remote web server hosts CGI scripts that fail to adequately sanitize request strings with malicious JavaScript. By leveraging this issue, an attacker may be able to cause arbitrary HTML to be executed in a user's browser within the security context of the affected site.

The remote web server may be vulnerable to IFRAME injections or cross-site scripting attacks :

- IFRAME injections allow 'virtual defacement' that might scare or anger gullible users. Such injections are sometimes implemented for 'phishing' attacks.
- XSS are extensively tested by four other scripts.
- Some applications (e.g. web forums) authorize a subset of HTML without any ill effect. In this case, ignore this warning.

Comment: Not laravel specific but htmlpurifier is the best php library for accepting html.

Comment: but when i use it, it's not prevent HTML Injections (quick test).

Comment: What did you inject and how did you utilize the library?  I'd be highly concerned if you were able to inject something when properly utilizing htmlpurifier.

Answer (score 0):

I often use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Complete the following steps
1.install

```
composer require "mews/purifier:~2.0"
```

2.setting

```
 php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider"
```

config/purifier.php

```
<?php

return [
    'encoding'      => 'UTF-8',
    'finalize'      => true,
    'cachePath'     => storage_path('app/purifier'),
    'cacheFileMode' => 0755,
    'settings'      => [
        'body' => [
            'HTML.Doctype'             => 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional',
            'HTML.Allowed'             => 'div,b,strong,i,em,a[href|title],ul,ol,ol[start],li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src],*[style|class],pre,hr,code,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,del,table,thead,tbody,tr,th,td',
            'CSS.AllowedProperties'    => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,margin,width,height,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align',
            'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => true,
            'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty'   => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

3. use

   $article->body = clean($article->body, 'body');

Hope useful to you!

Comment: It can prevent 2 case of my web security on nessus but still have another problem and I updated my question.